# How to render form output dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular

Hi I am new to angular 2 and apologize if this is a silly question.

I am trying to see if there is a way to render data on a form submit. Basically the form returns JSON fro ma get request and I want to know if its possible to return the json but rendered nicely(maybe in a table) onto to the page after clicking submit.

Im not looking for a written solution I just want to know how i can go about it.

tldr;
user submits info in form, form does http request and returns json.
can i display on the page nicely in a table?

Thanks and again sorry if this is a dumb question..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. This question is too generic. Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you have tried and where you failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i usual do it:

**Fetching the data**

Start by parsing the response into a model/object, for example:

```
http.post(someUrl, body).subscribe((res) => this.model = res.json())
```

When the request is successful, the callback in subscribe will be called

**Displaying the data**

Then in the html you can check if the model is not-null, and if it is, draw the model (using a table or whatever):

```
<div *ngIf="model">
    // Do something else with your model here
    {{ model }}
</div>
```